# Cypress linting and type check is ignored on command line but works fine on VS Code

Tags: typescript, jestjs, cypress, eslint

I have a nest.js + cypress with TS setup. Inside VS Code both typings and linter rules work as expected, format on save works and everything seems fine.

On the CLI when running the command below, cypress errors are not caught.

```sh
tsc --noEmit
```

The same is true for eslint

```sh
eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.{ts,tsx}\"
```

I have the following files:

tsconfig.base.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json (that excludes cypress)

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@src/*": ["src/*"],
      "@tests/*": ["tests/api/*"]
    },
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "watchOptions": {
    "excludeDirectories": ["sessions", "src/client/.next", "tests/cypress"],
    "excludeFiles": ["src/client/next-env.d.ts"]
  },
  "include": ["src", "tests"],
  "exclude": ["tests/cypress"]
}
```

And tests/cypress/tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.base.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "types": ["cypress"],
    "noEmit": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "include": ["./**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": []
}
```

As I said everything works perfectly on VS Code. On the cli the cypress files are "invisible", or if I remove the "exclude" from the main tsconfig.json the typings conflict with jest, with outputs such as:

```
Property 'to' does not exist on type 'JestMatchers<any>'.
```

I am aware of [cypress jest typescript example](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-and-jest-typescript-example) and they resort to running 2 linter commands.

Is there any way for me to make tsc and eslint behave on a similar manner as vsCode?

Thank you very much.

Comment: To get `tsc` to process the Cypress files, which you've explicitly excluded from the default project, you'd need to run _that specific project_ - `tsc --noEmit --project ./tests/cypress/tsconfig.json`.

Comment: That is what I resorted to but is there a way for it to respect the hierarchical tsconfigs? I would love to have a single command that upon stumbling on a folder with a new tsconfig considered it from that point onwards.